# Visual Studio 2010 Manage Output Files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'm new about code developing with Visual Studio 2010 and I would like to ask you a simple question about something after build a project.

I have a C# project and when I build It in Release mode some file are created and some of them copied from another in to \output\bin\Release\ folder. My question is that How can I manage that which created dll or created file will be in \output\bin\Release\ folder.

I tried to take a look at build properties of project but I could not find any option about it.

Thank you.

Comment: ignore the files in `/output/bin/Release`, you don't need them, just concentrate on the `bin/release` folder

Comment: The Copy Local property of the assembly reference determines if it will be copied.  In general you do not want to mess with it, VS gets it right 99% of the time.

Comment: Maybe I could not explain you that problem properly sorry for that. The main problem is that when I building my project, I see some dll and pdb files from another project output folder. Actually I do not need this dll in my project output folder because I add this dlls as a reference to my project.

Comment: None of the files in the output folder you will need to run your program, they are there for visual studio (not sure if there are some discrepancies in this bug im 99% sure of this, I never check them into version control and doesn't affect my programs functionality)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Actually I do not need this dll in my project output folder because I
>   add this dlls as a reference to my project

And this is exactly why this file appear in output folder.

There are several ways to "put" file in output folder. For normal files in the project you can set property `Copy to Output Directory`.

If we talking about dll's, (as mentioned Hans), there is `Copy Local` property for each assembly in References.

By default VS set this according to our GAC, so if you are using 3rd part assembly or from another project VS will set this property to `True` and file will be copied to output folder.

If you don't want to put this file in output folder, just set this property to `False`. But remember, at run time this assembly should exist.

For more information: [How to: Set the Copy Local Property of a Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1zz5y8c.aspx)

Another explanation: you just messed up with `Output path` in the project properties and two project has the same output folder. :)

Comment: Maybe I messed up the project:). I tried the set false to Copy Local property of a reference that I have added, but it still exist in Output folder when I build the project. I will search more about his issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I've solve the problem by setting Copy Local property to false.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you ignore the extra files that are created. One way to do this is to configure the destination of these to a different location. 
I use this:

property pages->General 
- Output Directory = $(SolutionDir)..\link\ 
- Intermediate Directory = c:\temp\vc10\$(SolutionName)\$(Configuration)\

Use the same settings for debug and release.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try it and inform you.